# Is there are a way of finding when a class is used with static analysis in python?

Tags: python, static-analysis

I have a moderately large monorepo code base. There are two classes that have the same name. I was interested as to whether there was a way of find the uses of just one of these class distinguishing classes with the same name using inference.

Example:

```py
# file client1.schema
class ObjectIdField: # <- I want to audit the uses of this class
    ...

# file client.schema
class ObjectIdField: # <- I don't want to audit the use of this class
   ...

# file project 1
from client1.schema import ObjectIdField
ObjectIdField()

# file project 2
from client2.schema import ObjectIdField
ObjectIdField()
```

Comment: Can you show the import statements for the class you want to have and the class you want to ignore?

Comment: added this exchange

Comment: Did you try PyCharm "FindUsage" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your import statement is the key.

In your example above, your static analysis could parse all code for `ObjectIdField` but *only* the usages `from client1.schema`.

As suggested by @balderman in comments, you could select an object instantiation of `ObjectIdField()` and Ctrl-B ("Go to definition") in PyCharm. This should take you to the definition in either `client1.schema` or `client.schema`. PyCharm will figure out from the import statement which one was correct.